# Let G = (V, E) be a graph. Let $S \subseteq V$ be such that $v(G) = \frac{1}{2}(|V| + |S| - oc(G-S))$, show that..

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Let G = (V, E) be a graph. Let $S \subseteq V$ be such that $v(G) = \frac{1}{2}(|V| + |S| - oc(G-S))$, where v(H) denotes the cardinality of a maximum matching of H and oc(H) denotes the number of odd components of a graph H.

I need to show that:

- In every maximum matching, the nodes in S are matched to nodes in different odd com- ponent of G − S.
- Every even component of G − S has a perfect matching.
- Every odd component of G − S has a matching with only one exposed node.

**Question:** How do I do this? I have no clue whatsoever..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @M.Winter Thanks, edited.

Comment: You might get inspired by a proof to [tutte's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem).

Comment: @M.Winter Done :)